# Reset atom editor file tree

Tags: atom-editor

I've tried looking but can't find a shortcut to reset the file tree in Atom editor. Is there a way to collapse all the files? I've tried right clicking and looking into the menu to no avail.

Comment: To the close voter: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**." Questions about text-editors certainly fall under that category, and you see them quite often. That is why these tags exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Opt</kbd>-click (Mac) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click (Win/Linux) to collapse or expand everything under a directory.

Be warned though, if your tree is at all large, especially if it encloses something with a lot of sub-items such as a `.git` directory, a library or template dir with a lot of files, it can be very slow, and it will block Atom UI until it is finished. YMMV.